# Match Data of 2 Excel Sheets where Column Names are Different

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 2 Excel Sheets both put into a Pandas Dataframe.

Ex:

```
1.csv
EmployeeID | DOB        | Age
A          | 12/11/1978 | 2
B          | 12/09/1988 | 8
C          | 12/02/1985 | 20
D          | 11/11/1990 | 25 

2.csv
MemberIdentifier| DateofBirth| YOW
A               | 12/11/1978 | 2
B               | 12/09/1988 | 8
C               | 12/02/1985 | 20

result.csv
EmployeeID | MemberIdentifier | DOB        |DateofBirth| Exp | YOW
A          |       A          | 12/11/1978 | 12/11/1978| 2   | 2
B          |       B          | 12/09/1988 | 12/09/1988| 8   | 8
C          |       C          | 12/02/1985 | 12/02/1985| 20  | 20
D          |       NA         | NA         | NA        | NA  | NA
```

Now how do I get a result which compares both the sheets based on the data not on the basis of column names because column names can be anything.

Any hint hint or idea of how to start will be great!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parameters `left_on` and `right_on` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='EmployeeID', right_on='MemberIdentifier', how='left')
print (df)
  EmployeeID         DOB  Age MemberIdentifier DateofBirth   YOW
0          A  12/11/1978    2                A  12/11/1978   2.0
1          B  12/09/1988    8                B  12/09/1988   8.0
2          C  12/02/1985   20                C  12/02/1985  20.0
3          D  11/11/1990   25              NaN         NaN   NaN
```

If need match columns in two `DataFrames` use:

```
d = {}
for col2 in df2.columns:
    for col1 in df1.columns:
        cond = df2[col2].isin(df1[col1]).all()
        if cond:
            d[col2] = col1

print (d)
{'MemberIdentifier': 'EmployeeID', 'DateofBirth': 'DOB', 'YOW': 'Age'}
```

Last you can rename columns by `dict`:

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns=d)
print (df2)
  EmployeeID         DOB  Age
0          A  12/11/1978    2
1          B  12/09/1988    8
2          C  12/02/1985   20
```

Comment: The problem is the 2nd CSV column names could be anything and we are not sure of that. What I have provided is just an example. So is there any way to compare based on data rather than column names?

Comment: Is possible get position of unknown name column? Of not?

Comment: Yes, is possible compare first column of `df1` with all columns of `df2`. But how we know it is same? If only match 1, 3 values ? What if values are shifted and no match?

Comment: Yes, can we match first column of df1 and df2 and do something like it contains()? And if there is a match club them together in a new data frame.

Comment: So you need match first column in `df1` with first column in `df2` ?

Comment: If need compare it `print (df2[df2.columns[0]].isin(df1.EmployeeID))`

Comment: Ideally, loop df1 columns through df2 columns to find a match as we have no idea where the data would be in df2. And if there is a match club them together in a new data frame so that we can get results.csv as shown above in my question.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question - I have a df1 with columns and df2 with columns but the column names of both data frame don't match  and df2 is not in order too but the data does match. So how do I match 2 data frame based on data not column names because both are different?

Comment: oops, answer is ok?

Comment: If you could reply an solution to my previous comment where I have rephrased my question then it would be great. I am trying to workaround with what you have suggested. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, sure. But give me a time, because a bit complicated.

Comment: Please see edit. I create dictionary of matches. Is it ok?

Comment: It works like a charm, but why it is not displaying the value in 'd' if I add new columns to it. And how can I insert the values below when i use -> print(d).

Comment: How do you add new value? In dict has to be unique keys, maybe this is problem.

Comment: Is there a way to add the values below the column heading that we have printed out in the end??

Comment: Hmmm, I have an idea, give me a sec.